# How do I take a derivative of a function that depends on another function in *general form*?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Can someone explain how to take the full derivative of a function written in general form where that function depends on another function?

We have the function:

$$v(a) = u(x(a),a)$$

Find $\frac{dv}{da}$.

So how would you go about this? I have tried using the chain rule, but get the wrong answer (I think).

My try:

$$\frac{dv}{da} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial a}$$

The correct answer should be:

[image]

So am I doing it all wrong, or is it a notational thing?

Comment: What are the domains and ranges of your functions? We need to know that first.

Comment: I will try to answer. It's not explicitly given, but x(a) is the value of x that solves a unconstrained maximisation problem. It's in economics and u(.)  is probably a utility-function implying u(.) > 0. So my guess is that the domain is all positive real numbers . Range is 0 to infinity I think. (Sorry if I've missused domain / range, as I'm a bit unsure of the definitions).

Comment: On the RHS you do not take the derivative of $v$. You take the derivative of $u$. And it seems that $x$ is a kind of constant. Thus $\frac{dx}{d\alpha}=0$. With more specific information we can give a more specific answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added the rhs by mistake. It is zero by the use of the envolope theorem (not sure if this is widely known). Anyway, I removed the rhs, is it possible to evaluate now?

Comment: Since $v=u$ then $\frac{\partial v}{\partial u}=1$. Thus your equation $\frac{dv}{da} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial a}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial a}$ is a bad application of the chain rule. Two times $\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}$ is one in excess. Also there is a typo because $\frac{\partial a}{\partial a}=1$. It should be $\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$.

Comment: Fixed the typo @JJacquelin. But I don't quite follow. Why is $v = u$ and why does this imply $\frac{\partial a}{\partial a}=1$? Sorry if this is obvious...

Comment: You wrote : We have the function: $v(a) = u(x(a),a)$. And $u=v$ implies $\frac{du}{dv}=1$ like $f=x$ implies $\frac{df}{dx}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not applying the chain rule in the appropriate way. You have a function $u$ which depends on two variables, say $a$ and $b$, i.e., $u(b,a)$. Then you are composing with the map
$$
a\mapsto (x(a),a)
$$
obtaining $v(a)=u(x(a),a)$.
So you have
$$
\frac{dv}{da}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial b} \frac{dx}{da}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\cdot 1=u_b \frac{dx}{da}+u_a
$$

Comment: Great! I think this should be correct. I will check when I get a minute...

Comment: The point is that in your book are taking $u_x$ instead of $u_b$, but I consider this is an abuse of notation, since they are considering $x=x(a)$, mixing the name of the variable with the name of the function. But it is a standard abuse.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand most of it now. One thing though, where does the $\cdot 1$ come from from?

Comment: From $\frac{da}{da}=1$